# Can I run a script on reboot once?

Tags: bash, shell, centos, cron, reboot

CentOS9

Keeping in mind this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1099284/centos-how-to-keep-previous-service-state-on-reboot

It seems that it is not possible to achieve what I need. Is that correct?

What I need - to run a script which stops a service, collects and zips logs, then updates OS and reboots (in case there were kernel updates). My problem is that after the reboot the service starts again. It is undesirable.

One way to solve it would be to somehow make CentOS to run a script on this particular reboot, NOT any reboot. So this script can only be run after reboot from the script described above. The scripts stops the service again..

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "flag" file and an `@reboot` `cron` job:

```
#!/bin/bash
# flag file must exist across reboots 
flag="/tmp/myflagfile"
#
# if there is no $flag, this is the 1st time
if [[ ! -f "$flag" ]] ; then
  touch "$flag"
  do_firsttime
else
  rm "$flag"
  do_secondtime
fi
```

You can control behavior by creating (or not) the `$flag` file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you need, but I see two ways to do what you described:

- Make a "proper shutdown" script. Manage logs from it, set the file-flags for the next run (which would be read by the startup scripts on the next boot), manage services, etc. And then do the shutdown from the script itself. After the script is ready, go to the WM you are using and put that script instead of normal shutdown button.
- Write an application (C would be the easiest for this) which catch SIGTERM, SIGINT, etc (`man 7 signal`). Start that application as a demon on the machine boot. Once the app catch SIGTERM - call the log-gathering script.

And if you need that script to not run in the next work session, you can always set it up as service and be subject to normal service management (`man systemd`). Or your script can check existence of some flag-file - if it exist exit immediately with removing (or not) that flag-file (which would affect next session).

Comment: ok the flag-file idea seems ok. the paragraph 2 - it can be done by script on cron @reboot - no need for C program.

Answer (score 0):

I have split the script to 2 different jobs. One is running OS update and reboot and another (an hour later) is whatever is needed for logs collecting/zipping.